# Gray bracket line when coding in vs2015 dot.net core MVC connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I'm following an online course about asp.net core 
While editing in vs2015 something strange happened and i wonder what causes this.

```
public class MariaController
{
    [HttpGet("/")]
    public string Index() => "Hello from index mvc";
   [HttpGet("/Maria")]
    public string Maria() => "Hello from Maria mvc";
}
```

In above code the bracket code [....] uses colors as VS2015 should do too.
But the strange thing overhere is the text becomes completely gray, i'm puzzled of what can cause that. if I putt marks for it ea //[....]  it gets comment collor, and then if i remove comment and edit the text between [..changed] i'm getting color notation back, but as soon as i hit enter again that whole line [..changed..] becomes light gray again.
I wonder if i hit something wrong. one moment it looked good the other moment they all went gray.. and well i didnt went into the menu's is this some config issue perhaps ?.

Answer (score 0):

the cause here was vs2015 plugin supercharger, it isnt aware of the language tricks in mvc 6